# Chrome displays glitches on webpages

Tags: google-chrome, mac

I'm on a Mac running version `10.15.4` and am running Chrome version  `80.0.3987.163`.
I've recently started to experience visual glitches on webpages in the form of blue bars. Sometimes this occurs when I immediately visit the page, other times it starts after I initially scroll. It also doesn't occur on every webpage and there doesn't seem to be an obvious pattern just yet of which webpages have this issue. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling chrome and restarting my computer. Does anyone know what the cause of this issue might be?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Preferences and disable Hardware acceleration.